# python itertools.islice() implementation

Tags: python, python-itertools

Implementation link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

```
def islice(iterable, *args):
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2) --> A B
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, 4) --> C D
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 2, None) --> C D E F G
    # islice('ABCDEFG', 0, None, 2) --> A C E G
    s = slice(*args)
    start, stop, step = s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxsize, s.step or 1
    it = iter(range(start, stop, step))
    try:
        nexti = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        # Consume *iterable* up to the *start* position.
        for i, element in zip(range(start), iterable):
            pass
        return
    try:
        for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
            if i == nexti:
                yield element
                nexti = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        # Consume to *stop*.
        for i, element in zip(range(i + 1, stop), iterable):
            pass
```

I don't understand the function of the following two parts of this implementation:

**First part**:

```
# Consume *iterable* up to the *start* position.
for i, element in zip(range(start), iterable):
    pass
return
```

**Second part**:

```
# Consume to *stop*.
for i, element in zip(range(i + 1, stop), iterable):
    pass
```

Aren't they inconsequential due to the `StopIteration`?

Comment: *"Aren't they inconsequential due to the `StopIteration`?"* - the `StopIteration` comes from the `iter(range(...))` iterator, not the input `iterable`. And it's purpose is to exhaust the `iterable` (just like the comments in the code state...)

Comment: For example if you do `list(islice(my_iterable, 0, 50, 15))`, followed by `next(iterable)`, the result of `next` is `iterable[50]` even though the last thing yielded by `islice` was `iterable[45]`.

Comment: No, both parts are relevant, but only for _iterators_, ie. when the `iterable` is an iterator: The first part makes sure that in case of arguments that lead to an empty slice the iterator's position is advaned to `start`. The second part makes sure that after a slicing that doesn't stops just before the `stop` position, the iterater is advanced accordingly (eg. `range(0, 5, 3)` stops at `3`, not `4`).